# LeafletJS lock map center

Tags: leaflet, openstreetmap

Is there an easy way to lock the center of a map?

You can disable dragging / panning easily with `map.dragging.disable();` but that doesn't make the center of the map fixed. Searched for it in the documentations and on the web but can't find anything.

Answer (score 2):

The [`maxBounds` option](http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.0.0.html#map-maxbounds) (paired with `maxBoundsViscosity`) should do the trick - just convert the `LatLng` you want to be centered into a zero-area `LatLngBounds`.

Comment: I still can't get it to work... maxBounds: [[50.84464,4.35254],[50.84465,3.5255]] and maxBoundViscosity: 1 should do the job as I understand what you are saying?

Comment: I need to be able to zoom in and out without changing the map's center regardless the position of the mouse.

Answer (score 1):

Use the option [`scrollWheelZoom: "center"`](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.7.1.html#map-scrollwheelzoom) to fix zooming with the scroll wheel to the center of the map.

```js
var map = L.map('map', {
    center: [0,0],
    dragging: false,
    scrollWheelZoom: "center",
});
```